# I accidentally clicked never allow java to run a game from steam and now it wont ask again

Tags: windows-8, java

I downloaded a game from steam and it came up with a java pop-up and I wasn't thinking and clicked never allow. Now it won't start the game and I cant figure out how to get it to pop up the java thing again.

Comment: which game is it / was it the firewall or av that asked you?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the *Java Control Panel* (you can type *Configure Java* in the *Search Programs and files* in the menu bar) then click on the *Security* tab and then press *Restore Security Prompts*. Next time you should be able to redo your decision on the specific applet.